# Validity of trivial universally quantified formula with equality.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Assume that there is formula 
$\forall x : x \approx a$.
Is this valid in first order logic?

Performing Hebrandization would suggest not with $c_1 \approx a$.

But then the Hebrand universe is just the set $\{a\}$. So if $x$ can only be $a$ this would be valid by the reflexivity of equality.

Is this just because Skolemization (and Hebrandization) extends the Hebrand universe? i.e the Hebrand universe is actually $\{a, c_1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, $\forall x (x=a)$ is not *universally valid*.

Consider e.g. a domain $D = \{ 0,1 \}$ and interpret the constant $a$ with e.g. $0$.

But the formula is *satisfiable* in every domain with a single element.

And this is what the [Herbrand universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_universe) shows : the satisfiability of the formula.

Comment: does that mean that any formula that relies upon the validity of a subformula that includes a universally quantified variable $x$ in an equality relation (both $\approx$ and $\not\approx$) will always be invalid? (ignoring the case of $x \approx x$)

Comment: @beoliver - not very clear... But in general, a formula $\forall x (x = \ldots)$ must be "filled" with a *term*. A term is a "name" denoting an object of the domain. So, due to the fact that in a specified domain $D$ the term must have a denotation $d$, it is quite obvious that a formula asserting that "every object is $d$" will be TRUE only when $d$ is the only existsing object.